# Installed xmonad, broke gnome desktop

Tags: gnome, metacity, xmonad

I installed xmonad a couple of nights ago. Xmonad includes the files that you would need select it from GDM (e.g. /usr/share/applications/xmonad.desktop and /usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop).

I tried starting xmonad via gdm and locked up X... (eventually even the virtual terminals locked up and I had to reboot the machine). The next time I started the machine I selected gnome instead of xmonad, it launched gnome-session, but tried to run xmonad instead of metacity as the desktop environment (this was entirely unusable). I moved the xmonad.desktop files in both /usr/share/applications and /usr/share/xsessions, now I have no desktop environment (which is slightly usable). How do I re-enable metacity?

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal,

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-window-manager
```

will probably do the trick. Alternatively you can

```
sudo apt-get purge xmonad
```

and that should do the trick also.

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I get home. I was considering purging xmonad, but I would actually like to get it to work...

Comment: Hm... I ran that, but a) metacity was already selected and b) even re-selecting it didn't fix the problem. I *can* run metacity from a gnome-terminal, but that's a workaround, not a fix.